# Angular app post to MVC webapi back end returns 405

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an angular/MVC app combo.  A user goes in  can modify a record  clicks a a button calls a service that does a post to update a record in the DB.  It hits the controller (I have  breakpoint on the constructor) but, not the method and throws back a 405.

Button Click handler:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
    console.log($scope.request);
    requests.updateRequest($scope.request).then(onUpdate, onError);
}
```

Request resource:

```
var updateRequest = function (request) {
    return $http.post("/api/request/update/", request).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
};
```

The routes are configured in a separate file:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("UpdateRequest", "api/request/update/", new { controller = "Requests", action = "UpdateRequest"});
```

The RequestController constructor gets hit but, I am unable to work out why the following endpoint is not hit.

Controller method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateRequest([FromBody] IRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content =
                    new ObjectContent(
                    typeof(int),
                    request.Id,
                    new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
            };
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }   
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried a few variations on the endpoint method.  One that accepts an object as a parameter and also tried using httpput instead.  

Note. the resource service does work as I have a Get method which retrieves the data in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameter binding doesn't work with interfaces. Try changing:

> [FromBody] IRequest request

to a concrete type e.g.

> Request request

If you do want to use an interface in your webapi check out [this blog post](https://brettedotnet.wordpress.com/2014/07/16/web-api-and-interface-parameters/)

Comment: Thats a really obvious point that!  thanks, cant believe I missed it!

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately.  I now get the dreaded 
POST http://localhost:52961/api/request/update/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Despite the fact that I have ET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS  allowed in the web.config.

Comment: leave it as HttpPost, otherwise you will have to do additional config to get put\delete to work. Is this the only HttpPost method in your controller? might be easier to show whole controller class code

Comment: Also try removing your config.route.MapHttpRoute line. If your HttpPost method is the only one in the class it will be chosen by default. If it isn't add a routing attribute above the function